# Call variable in call stacks

Tags: powershell, variables, function-calls

I came across some code and couldn't understand why PowerShell can pass the value not in the function. Hope someone could kindly help.

Here's the revised code structure:

```
  function ServerSetup () {

  param (
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
  [string] $Environment
)

 CreateFolder 
} 

function CreateFolder () {

$Environment = $Environment+"test2"
$Environment
}
```

My question is for `$Environment` parameter above, it’s not passed via the param (only `$JsonObject`), how come it still can get the value?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If that is completely all of the code then I would be confused as well. I suspect that it is not all of the code.

Comment: If the variable was defined in a higher scope then it would not need to be passed. If Get-Value used it's -Environment parameter in such a way that a $null would not throw an error it would not need to be defined at all. Without seeing the code we cannot tell you how the code works.

Comment: @EBGreen Thanks a lot for your comments.

Comment: @EBGreen I've updated the code, hope it helps for understanding the issue.
for the Get-value function, I've already used the debugger to track the $Environment value and it actually passed the right value to the Get-value function...

Comment: for simplicity, i tried the revised version above

the result is testtest2, so I think @EBGreen is right, If the variable was defined in a higher scope then it would not need to be passed.